# A more efficient way to process a large amount of files (300k+) in order to collect results?

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, performance

I have a file named `fields.txt` and containing `L=300k+` lines which looks like:

```
field1 field2 field3
field1 field2 field3
field1 field2 field3
... 
field1 field2 field3
```

In the same folder, I have `N` files containing only one string (let's identify it `s(n)`) and named `res-0-n-0` , with `n` anywhere between `0` and `L`. However `N < L`.

I generated the file `res_numbers_sorted.tmp` containing the numerically sorted list of the above-mentioned `n` with the command (not sure if the most efficient, but it is reasonably fast and I need this sorted for other purposes)

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "res-0-*" | sort -t'-' -k3 -n | awk -F'-' '{print $3}'>| res_numbers_sorted.tmp
```

The file `res_numbers_sorted.tmp` looks like:

```
0
1
8
... 
299963
```

Finally, what I want is a file named `results.txt` which would like:

```
field1 field2 field3 s(0)
field1 field2 field3 s(1)
field1 field2 field3
...
field1 field2 field3 s(299963) 
...
field1 field2 field3
```

where again `s(n)`is the string contained in the n-th `res-0-n-0`.

I have achieved what I want first by `cp fields.txt resutls.txt` and then with the following `while` loop:

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do 
     #storing the content of the file in a variable
     res=$(<res-0-"$line"-0)     
     # this is needed in order to take into account that sed addresses the first line of a file with the number 1 whereas the file list starts with 0
     real_line=$(( line + 1 ))     
     sed -i "${real_line}s/.$/ ${res}/" field.txt
done < res_numbers_sorted.tmp
```

However this is very slow and I need to perform this several times. I suspect that maybe `sed` is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: sed is not a bad tool for the job, the issue is that you iterate on the same file over and over. What you could do is generate a sed script by iterating on `res_numbers_sorted.tmp`, and then applying it once on `field.txt`. Maybe this would improve perfomance

Comment: I compared the two solutions proposed (the `sh` script and the `sed` based one) with `time`. Both the solutions are much faster than mine with the former displaying this result: `real 875.849 user 48.629 sys 92.359 pcpu 16.09`and the latter this result: `real 244.680 user 136.436 sys 9.536 pcpu 59.65` . Therefore I am choosing the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a`fields.txt`file with many line. You have several `res-0-n-0` files. And, for each line in `fields.txt` you what to copy them in `results.txt` with, if it exist, the content of the `res-0-<line_number>`file.

I think you can simply read the `fields.txt` file line by line and echo the line in the `results.txt`with the content of `res-0-<line_number>`file if needed.

I would go with something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

LINE_NUMBER=0
while read line;
do
  if [ -f "res-0-$LINE_NUMBER-0" ]
  then
    echo "$line $(cat res-0-$LINE_NUMBER-0)" >> result.txt
  else
    echo "$line" >> result.txt
  fi
  ((LINE_NUMBER++))
done < fields.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try generating a sed script and then applying it only once on you file `field.txt` :

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    res=$(<res-0-"$line"-0)
    real_line=$(( line + 1 ))
    prinft "%s" "${real_line}s/.$/ ${res}/" >> myscript.sed
done < res_numbers_sorted.tmp
```

and then do :

```
sed -i -f myscript.sed field.txt
```

This way, you only iterate once over your large file. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good solution, but I am choosing the other one as it is faster